# Nodejs: server doesn't close TCP connections

Tags: ssl, connection, node.js, limits

Facing a problem in the production server running debian (7.0) with nodejs (v0.10.x) cluster where it doesn't close **some** TCP connections to the clients.

This leads to connection drops when connection limit is reached.

Using `ss -s` tool I can monitor that some connections are closed after a while but some are not.

Here is the `sysctrl` config changes I use in order to increase maximum connections as temporary workaround:

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65500
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 16384 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 786432 1048576 26777216
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2000
```

How to find the bottleneck and solve the problem?

Comment: How solid is your code? Maybe there are some cases where the last callback is never called?

Comment: @Bazze the code looks solid. Also there is a 2 min default timeout for that case, so connection will be closed even if there missed callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `https` server doesn't inherit sockets timeout logic from `http` server.

There is a [patch](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5361) merged since Apr 2013, but it still doesn't merged to stable `0.10` branch.

The solutions:

- avoid `https` usage, use some proxy server (nginx);
- custom timeout handle;
- use node version higher than `0.10`.